# How to convert current timestamp in timeago in codeigneiter

Tags: php, jquery, date, time, timeago

I want to show time ago format from the cuurrent datetime in codeigneiter 3

And I want to convert this code to hours ago

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello please follow this

echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('@1367367755'); # timestamp input
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);

function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);

$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

$string = array(
   
    'y' => 'year',
    'm' => 'month',
    'w' => 'week',
    'd' => 'day',
    'h' => 'hour',
    'i' => 'minute',
    's' => 'second',
   
);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}

if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Comment: Thanku sir but I have done this through timespan

Comment: i am giving you 3 ways

echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35');
echo time_elapsed_string('@1367367755'); # timestamp input
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01 00:22:35', true);